# removeProp() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input and I want to disable it but it doesn't work at all. Even phpstorm says the function doesn't exist for some reason.. I thought it's a problem with phpstorm, but I tried it in Chrome and it doesn't work.

Is there any alternative or am I doing something wrong? I must point out that `button.css('pointer-events', 'none');` works but `removeProp` doesn't for some reason..

```
function waitComment() {
    var button = $(".btn-primary");
        button.css('pointer-events', 'none');
    setTimeout(function(){
        button.remove('pointer-events');
    }, 3000)
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" name="comment" id="#comment" class="comment" onclick="waitComment()">
```

Comment: Try `button.removeAttr('style');`.

Comment: `pointer-events` is not a property of `button` (i.e. you can't do `button.pointerEvents`).

Comment: why aren't you using the `disabled` attribute instead of messing with CSS properties?

Comment: +Alnitak disabled is bugged for me.. when a user clicks on it twice it stop beings disabled. and i find pointer-events to be better.

Comment: @flex_ then figure out why it's bugged - disabling pointer events won't completely disable the control because it could still respond to keyboard events.

Comment: +Rocket hazamat  it doesn't work... chrome doesn't even give error. weird

Comment: @flex_ if you're using a timer to re-enable the button it's no surprise that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Alnitak Um, you can use a timer.... nothing wrong with that...

Comment: @epascarello I guess it's OK so long as it actually does prevent use of the button, but otherwise there's nothing to prevent unexpected interleaving or stacking of enable / disable sequences.

Comment: @flex_ do you understand that he is saying that it is not a property it is a CSS style rule declaration you are trying to remove, hence why you can not remove it as a property.

Comment: @flex_ You are doing a disservice to the future SO community by ignorantly accepting and upvoting an improper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to achieve your goal is,

**CSS**

```
.pointer{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
function waitComment() {
    var button = $(".btn-primary");
        button.addClass('pointer');
    setTimeout(function(){
        button.removeClass('pointer');
    }, 3000)
}
```

**Why .removeProp() didn' work?**

Jquery `.removeProp()` is for Html attributes/properties not for CSS properties.

Please find the Api reference of [.removeProp](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

Comment: this worked perfectly and as i required. appreciate it thanks

Comment: @flex_: Glad to hear it worked for you:). Click the tick icon in the answer.

Comment: Although this is by far superior to `.css()`, I would recommend also explaining why his solution did not work (for future users).

Comment: @ErikPhilips that's not needed since i got downvoted. keith and alnitak seems to hate me

Comment: You only have 1 downvote, and I said recommended... not required :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips check again mate :)

Comment: @flex_: It happens for me lot of time. The community is for give and get answers. Don't worry too much on that.

Comment: @JqueryRock haha yeah i know that i just don't know why altinak and keith got very mad over a question. i was curious why should i use disabled and they didn't give me a reasonable answer until i asked three times. people like you are the ones who make stackoverflow a great community. thank you :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Thank you:)

Comment: @flex_ You didn't ask a reasonable question - it should have been completely obvious without further explanation that `disabled` is designed to do exactly what you needed.    This is a classic "XY Problem" - "I think the solution to my problem is Y (since I couldn't get X to work) but I can't make Y work either so how do I solve Y?".   Your real problem was why you couldn't get `disabled` to work properly.

Comment: also see my comment from 1 minute after you commented that you have problems with `disabled`   _" then figure out why it's bugged - disabling pointer events won't completely disable the control because it could still respond to keyboard events"_.   No further explanation should have been necessary.

Comment: @flex_ You still don't understand why disabled is the correct choice here... Using pointer-events: none will no longer trigger :hover states, nor display title attributes, which most of the time is a bad thing. Especially since you said you are using bootstrap, which has hover states on buttons and changes the mouse cursor when hovering over a disabled button. It also will not stop keyboard actions like tabbing into your control and typing a value..  It's your site, your code, and you can do whatever you want, but using the disabled attribute is the single correct way to disable a control.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to disable button, why don't you use `disabled` property?

```
function waitComment() {
    var button = $(".btn-primary");
        button.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        button.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak i don't want the button to be disabled the whole time... point-events does what i want

Comment: @flex_, then remove the disabled when you want it again.

Comment: @Keith then why not use pointer-events? its the same.. except that disabled looks better.

Comment: @flex_ It's not the same because, pointer-events are mouse/finger only.  For example press your button, and then press enter.  It will fire again..  Enter is the keyboard you see.  And again, how is disabled bugged, can you supply an example.

Comment: @Keith i used bootstrap disabled that's why it didn't work i assume.. what do you mean by disabled?? supply me with the CSS code needed to do the "disabled" thing you keep talking about e.g update your answer

Comment: Generally speaking `pointer-events: none` is not the same as `disabled`. This is especially true if you have an overlay to cover something but still want the clicks to fall through to whatever is behind. You can achieve this with `pointer-events:none` but not with `disabled`. For a button though disabled may work in practice.

Comment: @apokryfos `disabled` is the canonical standards-based way of making an input control unresponsive.

Comment: @flex_  There is now 2 examples of using disabled here, mine & pwolaq's.  There is no updating of answer required.

Answer (score 0):

In what way is disabled bugged?..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function waitComment() {
    var button = $(".btn-primary");
        button.attr('disabled','disabled');    
}
</script>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" name="comment" id="#comment" class="comment" onclick="waitComment()">
```

Comment: @flex_ actually, no, you haven't.  You said "it's bugged", but haven't adequately explained how or why you think so.  This shows that it isn't.  This is _the right way_ to disable a control.

Comment: @alnitak why is pointer-events not the right way? it does exactly the same lol

Comment: @Keith how is it not the same?

Comment: @flex_ because it only affects mouse events, not keyboard events.

Comment: regardless i will add cursor:not-allowed. will cursor:not-allowed stop that from happening ?

Comment: @flex_  are you trolling, disabled is the correct way to disable an input, that's why it's called disabled..

Comment: @keith doubt a troll would waste his time asking question lol. i wanna know why disabled is the correct way. i'm not trolling lol

Comment: @flex_ because it's _exactly_ what that attribute was _designed for_ !!

Comment: @flex_ "This Boolean attribute indicates that the control is not available for interaction" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function waitComment() {
            var button = $(".btn-primary");
            button.css('pointer-events', 'none');
           button.css('color', 'red');
            setTimeout(function () {
                button.css('pointer-events','');
               button.css('color', 'blue');
            }, 3000)
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" name="comment" id="#comment" class="comment" onclick="waitComment()">
</body>
</html>
```

1. here I added a effect on button as follows..

   - Initially button text color will be Black
   - on click button color will change to Red
   - on time out button color will change to Blue

Hope this make help you...

Thanks... :)